# Ionic cordova angular build not targeting correct environment

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic cordova angular app that I'm trying to build for different environments (prod vs local)

In the environments there's a file environment.prod.ts with the prod connection strings

and the following is in my angular.json file describing the environment

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
```

When I actually build with the below command though, it does not do the file replacement but just uses what's already in the plain environment.ts file

```
ionic cordova build browser -- -c=production
```

I also tried --env=production and a whole slew of other varieties. Am I missing a setting somewhere? Or what

Comment: I'm going to keep my eye on this as I have had the same problem recently. Until a few weeks ago "ionic cordova run ios --configuration=qa" ran like a charm. Now it does not swap out configs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me with:

```
ionic cordova build browser --prod
```

If you need more complex environments you can create a build.json and run it like:

```
ionic cordova build browser --buildConfig=build.json
```

for other environments rather than production:

```
ionic build -c=environment --engine=cordova --platform=browser
```

Comment: but how to target the normal angular environments like any other angular project? normally you'd just do `--configuration=configuration` per the angular docs. Nothing complex, just different enviro variables per

Comment: @JoshuaOhana I updated my answer above. Hope it helps